# Using of OR and AND function in Power bi

Tags: powerbi

I want to know the values if PM Frequency is > or = 12 and Hours< 8 or materials value is blank or service value is blank in Power bi. Below is the DAX formula I have written. Please help to correct this.

IF('PM Forecast Appended'[PM Frequency] >=12 && OR('PM Forecast Appended'[Plot Hours]<8, OR(ISBLANK('PM Forecast Appended'[Forecast Work Order/Route Estimate - Materials ($)]), OR(ISBLANK('PM Forecast Appended'[Forecast Work Order/Route Estimate - Services ($)]),1,0)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code-

```
IF(
    'PM Forecast Appended'[PM Frequency] >=12 
    && 
    (
        'PM Forecast Appended'[Plot Hours] < 8, 
        ||
        ISBLANK('PM Forecast Appended'[Forecast Work Order/Route Estimate - Materials ($)]) 
        ||
        ISBLANK('PM Forecast Appended'[Forecast Work Order/Route Estimate - Services ($)])
    ),
    1,
    0
)
```